# Why does python give me a TypeError for this function? (new to coding)

Tags: python, python-3.x

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IB0Yq.png

I'm new to coding and not sure why the list is being typed as a tuple.

Comment: Instead of adding image, you should add the source code directly to the question.

Comment: Please don't use images to show code. You may [edit] your question to copy and paste it here

Comment: And think about what the error says... You can't add a tuple to a list. Anyways `type(list) is list` is wrong because a type of a variable is not itself... Basically, do not name your variables by python datatypes or functions, such as `list`

Comment: Please paste the text of your code into the question and see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've used the same name, `list`, for both a built-in type and a local variable. Don't re-use the built-in names. Quoting [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments):

> If a function argument's name clashes with a reserved keyword, it is generally better to append a single trailing underscore rather than use an abbreviation or spelling corruption. Thus `class_` is better than `clss` . (Perhaps better is to avoid such clashes by using a synonym.)

Try:

```
def funct2(list_):
    if type(list_) == list:
        ...
```

Or, better:

```
def funct2(list_):
    if isinstance(list_, list):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function2(list_variable):
    #: dont use names that can shadow built in types
    #: like `int`, `list` etc

    if isinstance(list_variable, list):
        #: do something here
        list_variable.append(["a"]) #: to append a list i.e. ['b', ['a']]
        list_variable + ["a"]  #: also works but... `your cup of tea`
    elif isinstance(list_variable, tuple):
        #: you are trying to add a list `[]` to a tuple `("a",)`

        #: this is not allowed, how does the computer know if it is to
        #: convert your list to a tuple or your tuple to a list.
        #: this conversion is called coercion look it up
        #: Also read about immutability
        list_variable + ("a", )

    else:
        print("Sorry, only lists or tuples allowed")
```